# A class that extends HashMap when adding new variable can't be write to json

Tags: java, json

ResultContentExt extends HashMap and has it's own variable testInt.
In main method, I write the ResultContentExt been to json.but can't write the variable
testInt to json.
I also rewrite writeObject method in ResultContentExt, which seems not be called...

```
package test.open.serial;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class ResultContentExt extends HashMap<String, Object> implements
        Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 628377769976336650L;

    public ResultContentExt() {
    }

    private int testInt;

    public int getTestInt() {
        return testInt;
    }

    public void setTestInt(int testInt) {
        this.testInt = testInt;
    }

    public List<String> getRef_hot_status() {
        return (List<String>) this.get("ref_hot_status");
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ResultContentExt [ref_hot_status=" + this.getRef_hot_status()
                + "]" + "ref_new_status=" + this.getRef_new_status()
                + this.getTestInt();

    }

    public void setRef_hot_status(List<String> ref_hot_status) {
        if (ref_hot_status != null) {
            this.put("ref_hot_status", ref_hot_status);
        } else {
            this.put("ref_hot_status", new LinkedList<Map<String, Integer>>());
        }
    }

    public void setRef_new_status(List ref_new_status) {
        if (ref_new_status != null) {
            this.put("ref_new_status", ref_new_status);
        } else {
            this.put("ref_new_status", new LinkedList<Map<String, Integer>>());
        }
    }

    public List<String> getRef_new_status() {
        return (List<String>) this.get("ref_new_status");
    }

    public void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream s) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("ResultContentExt begin...");

        s.defaultWriteObject();
        System.out.println("ResultContentExt end");

    }
}
```

the result is {"ref_new_status":["bbbb","cccc"],"ref_hot_status":["aaa","侠盗飞"]}
why the testInt can't be write to json.

the main class

```
public class SearilazizeTest implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5767426158258564918L;
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SearilazizeTest.class);
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        jsonObjectTrans();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    }
}

public static void jsonObjectTrans(){
    ResultContentExt rce = new ResultContentExt();
    List<String> refHostStatus = new ArrayList<String>();
    refHostStatus.add("aaa");
    refHostStatus.add("侠盗飞");
    rce.setRef_hot_status(refHostStatus);
    List<String> refNewStatus = new ArrayList<String>();
    refNewStatus.add("bbbb");
    refNewStatus.add("cccc");
    rce.setRef_new_status(refNewStatus);

    rce.setTestInt(22);
    System.out.println(rce.getTestInt());
    JSONObject jsonArray = JSONObject.fromObject(rce);
    System.out.println(jsonArray);

    ResultContentExt packageVersionMaps = new ResultContentExt();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.fromObject(jsonArray);
        packageVersionMaps  = (ResultContentExt) JSONObject.toBean(jsonObject,ResultContentExt.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    }
    System.out.println(packageVersionMaps);

}}
```

Comment: So what's your specific question? And show your main method. I also dont see you writing anything to a JSON object (at least not in this code). Furthermore, you seem to only place `List<String>`s in the HashMap, so why don't you make it a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`?

Comment: Your `testInt` value is not accessible via the `Map` interface that would be used to construct the JSON.